# What's the best way to get a MySQL database into SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services?

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I'm trying to get a MySQL database into SQL Server 2012 reporting services as a shared data source, and getting absolutely nowhere after a day.

I've tried a couple of options. First, my specs:

Machine: Workstation running Windows 7 64 bit
SQL server: SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (evaluation)
MySQL version: 5.1.68-cll
ODBC version: MySQL ODBC 5.2 driver (both 5.2a and 5.2w)

Ok, now my attempts:

1. Create an ODBC connection and use this directly as a data source in MS SSRS.

This worked well initially, after a little mucking around I was able to get the ODBC connection working as a data source in the Report Manager interface.

The problem came when I went to use this data source in Report Builder 3.0. I was able to set this as the data source (connection tested fine). However, whenever I came to build a dataset from the data source, I always came up with this error: "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

I tried every solution I could find to fix this, no luck.

Then I came across a post that said using a connection like this in report builder is always problematic and limited, and the best way to do this was to create a linked server then use this as the data source.

So that was method 2:

I have been trying to create a linked server in MS SQL Management Studio to the MySQL database. I've entered all the details according to what info I could find on the web, but it always hangs when I create it. The green circle just sits there spinning, and stays like that till I crash the whole program.

The linked server shows up in the server browser when I restart again, but when I test the connection it freezes management studio again, and the only way out is to crash it.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this, I'm only fairly new to all this and this has just about driven me crazy.